# Cant reproduce (1 to 1) Mysql query in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to reproduce a mysql query search into rails (AR) model code. I tried several posts in the internet but none of them worked for me.

Here is the mysql query:

`SELECT id, title, content, created_at, match(title)  against ('alpha' in natural language mode) AS score FROM users.hubspot_blog_posts
where  match(title)  against ('alpha' in natural language mode) order by score desc, created_at desc;`

The idea is to fetch all titles that match the search pattern and order them, first by score, second (if the score is equal) by created_at date.

While the query above seems to work as I want, I wasnt able to translate it into rails code. Here is what I have tried, I get the same collection but different oredre:

`HubspotBlogPost.select("*, MATCH(title) AGAINST ('alpha' in natural language mode) AS score").where("MATCH(title) AGAINST('alpha' in natural language mode)", :order => "score desc, created_at desc")`

With the Mysql if the `score` is identical the order is made by date(created_at), but the ruby code doesnt care.

Please correct me and if possible let me know where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by is not an option to `where()` it's a method on it's own.

```
HubspotBlogPost.select(
  "*, MATCH(title) AGAINST ('alpha' in natural language mode) AS score"
).where(
  "MATCH(title) AGAINST('alpha' in natural language mode)"
).order(
  "score desc, created_at desc"
).to_sql
```

returns

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title) AGAINST ('alpha' in natural language mode) AS score FROM "customers" WHERE (MATCH(title) AGAINST('alpha' in natural language mode)) ORDER BY score desc, created_at desc
```

This can be made to look a bit better and safer by avoiding direct SQL.

```
HubspotBlogPost.select(
  HubspotBlogPost.arel_table[Arel.star],
  "MATCH(title) AGAINST ('alpha' in natural language mode) AS score"
).where(
  "MATCH(title) AGAINST('alpha' in natural language mode)"
).order(
  'score desc', created_at: :desc
).to_sql
```

The last raw sql can also be removed using Arel, but it's a bit more complicated. Look into it if you're interested.

Comment: Running this command gives

`NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Class:0x0000559f613c5b30>`

Comment: I apologize, in my personal setup I have a delegation that most people don't. I edited and fixed it.

Comment: Now I get different error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'hubspot_blog_posts.score' in 'order clause': SELECT  `hubspot_blog_posts`.*, MATCH(title) AGAINST ('alpha' in natural language mode) AS score FROM `hubspot_blog_posts` WHERE (MATCH(title) AGAINST('alpha' in natural language mode)) ORDER BY `hubspot_blog_posts`.`score` DESC, `hubspot_blog_posts`.`created_at` DESC LIMIT 11`

Comment: Fixed it. Not setting the environment up myself can bite I guess.

Comment: It works now. Is it possible to turn this crazy query into a scope?